# Install TL-WN725N in Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, wifi

Im new user of python, raspbian and raspberry pi. I would like to install new wifi adapter into my raspberry. But unfortunately, I not really understand and there's no proper instruction to install this thing. May anyone help me?

TP-Link 150Mbps Wireless N, Nano USB Adapter. TL-WN725

Comment: this question is answered here [ http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/17187/why-i-obtain-this-error-trying-to-install-tp-link-tl-wn725n-wireless-adapter-d/17188#17188 ]

Answer (score 0):

Hey there I had the same problemwith the TL-WN725N. Try these instruction. They worked for me.

To find out wht kernal version you are using then type in /lib/module in the folder window and it will show you.

Good Luck

http://www.mendrugox.net/2013/08/tp-link-tl-wn725n-v2-working-on-raspberry-raspbian/