# Why do I get this error trying to install TP-LINK (TL-WN725N) wireless adapter driver?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless, driver

I am very new in RaspBerry and I am using RaspBian distribution. I am going crazy to install the wifi USB adapter. The used model is a **TP-LINK TL-WN725N**

I followed this tutorial: http://laurenthinoul.com/how-to-install ... pberry-pi/

To these are the operations that I performed:

1) Update kernel version:

```
sudo apt-get install rpi-update
```

After this I obtain that the kernel version is the **3.12.20+**, infact:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/wirelessDriver $ uname -r
3.12.20+
```

2) Then I have update my system by:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo reboot
```

3) Then I downloaded and extract the driver by:

```
sudo wget -4 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80256631/8188eu-20140307.tar.gz
sudo tar -zxvf 8188eu-20140307.tar.gz
```

and now in the directory I only have the **8188eu.ko** file (in addition to the archive from which it was extracted), infact:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/wirelessDriver $ ls
8188eu-20140307.tar.gz  8188eu.ko
```

And then I have a first doubt: I skipped the following operation:

```
sudo cp rtl8188eufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi //not needed anymore if your operating system is above 3.10.33+
```

because my kernel version is above the 3.10.33+ but if I go into **/lib/firmware/rtlwifi** directory I have not the **rtl8188eufw.bin** file, infact this is the content of my **/lib/firmware/rtlwifi**

```
pi@raspberrypi /lib/firmware/rtlwifi $ ls
rtl8192cfw.bin     rtl8192cfwU.bin  rtl8192defw.bin  rtl8712u.bin
rtl8192cfwU_B.bin  rtl8192cufw.bin  rtl8192sefw.bin
```

I don't know if this is normal or if it could be a problem.

4) Then I performed the insomod command and I obtain an error:

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.12.20+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8188eu.ko
Error: could not insert module /lib/modules/3.12.20+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8188eu.ko: Invalid module format
```

Why it say to me **Error: could not insert module /lib/modules/3.12.20+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8188eu.ko: Invalid module format** ?

How can I solve this problem and correctly install my USB adapter driver? I am desperate...I googled but I can't found a solution

Tnx
Andrea

Comment: Consider as well that some rtl drivers in your kernel may also be possibly not be the ones in the original/mainline kernel source. See https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commit/e323a433012bd1942aec6f0e8b89690431fa78af and https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commit/91a6137b73a3b53ed5fd21bb1300e890d2f93a26. Those commits may have affected your kernel as well. Try to know the source of your kernel. My USB wifi module didn't work with those not from the mainline. Reverting the commit fixed it. I reported an issue but it was declined: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/566

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mismatch between your kernel headers and headers that used to compile the driver. so you should get the headers for your kernel and compile the driver from source.

look at [ [DHT11 module compilation error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15902/dht11-module-compilation-error) ] to see how to download kernel headers (how to install `rpi-source` )

`git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu` to download the driver source

get the source with command `sudo rpi-source`

go to source directory, run `make all` `sudo make install`.

Comment: does not work with the last version of SO Raspbian .. see the following link to solve the problem: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=62371